# A conflict exists with definition event in namespace internal

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new in as3. I get this error:

> A conflict exists with definition event in namespace internal.

I'm using same coding but different scene. I changed second scene.

```
var mysound:bila =new bila()
```

This is the code of my 1st scene, and success only in 1st scene:

```
var isItPlaying:Boolean = true;
var lastposition:Number = 0;
var mysound:izhar = new izhar();
var soundchannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
soundchannel = mysound.play(0,0);// playing sound in the channel
soundchannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete1);

function onPlaybackComplete1(event:Event):void
{
    lastposition = 0;
    soundchannel.stop();
    btn.btn_pause.visible = false;
    trace("finished");
    isItPlaying=false;
}
/************end of part 1********/

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playsound);*

function playsound(event:MouseEvent):void*
{
    if (! isItPlaying)
    {
        soundchannel = mysound.play(lastposition,0);
        btn.btn_pause.visible = true;
        isItPlaying = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lastposition = soundchannel.position;
        soundchannel.stop();
        btn.btn_pause.visible = false;
        /*trace(lastposition.toFixed(0), mysound.length.toFixed(0));*/
        isItPlaying = false;
    }

    soundchannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);*

    function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        lastposition = 0;
        soundchannel.stop();
        btn.btn_pause.visible = false;
        trace("finished");
        isItPlaying=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you importing any packages at the top of your code?

Answer (score 2):

The conflict is because you are declaring two variables with the same name in the same scope.

You declare the `event` variable as a parameter in your `playsound` function. Then you have a nested function `onPlaybackComplete` that declares a parameter with the same name.

To fix this, either rename one of the parameters to something else, or move the `onPlaybackComplete` function outside the `playsound` function so it has its own scope.

I'd prefer the second option, unless you need have that function nested for some specific reason.